# Time limit on puzzle games: yea or nay?

Tags: game-design, puzzle

Of course, it goes without saying that this can only work when the puzzle is randomly generated (say, something like minesweeper/bejeweled) and not hand-designed levels (such as trainyard, theseus & the minotaur etc).

I am currently thinking that this can instill a sense of urgency to the player and make them feel more challenged. Along with increasing the actual puzzle difficulty, a time restriction could be another way to increase difficulty, and the combination of both can be used as a way to give a sense of progress.

Also possibly, incremental time increases when solving parts of the puzzle (like time extensions in racing games) could be used for these games.

What I'm wondering about is, what's the accepted thought about using time limits? Would they work as I'm currently thinking or am I missing anything?

Comment: Why are you asking us, when you ought to be finding out with your playtesters?

Comment: @Jonathan Still early with no prototypes yet, and at the same time I want to know what others think.

Comment: Make it an option for the user before the game starts, and then keep two different scoreboards -- one for time-pressured mode, and the other for unlimited-time mode.  This way, you can **satisfy both types of players** and hopefully sell more copies of your game.

Comment: _"what's the accepted thought about using time limits"_ I don't think you will find any concrete answer to this because it's not a yes/no question.  You're really just talking about two different game modes that will attract different players.  Neither is inherently better or worse than the other in a global context.  @doppelgreener 's comment is on target: you need to find testers that _represent your target market_.  They will give you the feedback you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some thoughts about puzzle time limits:

1. You can have soft time-limits. With this, the game will not allow you to move to the next level because you didn't solve the puzzle in time, but you can still continue playing just to learn strategies, etc.
2. Many people play puzzle based games for relaxation purposes, so it might not make sense in certain scenarios.
3. A tiered reward system (5 stars for < 1 min, 4 stars for < 1:30) might make sense. This allows those who want to get the highest score, get the highest score, and those who don't care will still be able to progress.
4. Some non-random puzzle games still have time limits. There is a graph coloring game for iOS (whose name I can't think of) that has pre-made levels whose main goal is to beat under the time limit. The actual puzzle is easy, but the time limit is the main cause of difficulty

Comment: Awarding stars for completing faster a *randomly*-generated puzzle, rewards those who were lucky enough to get an "easier" version of the puzzle. Awarding stars for completing faster a static puzzle of course makes no sense because you can just re-do it once you have the solution (unless there is action involved).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you say that time limits can't work on hand-designed levels. I'd say that they're more reasonable on hand-designed levels, because you can test and work out what the minimum time necessary is and what a reasonable extension is for the limit.

However, a hard time limit (out of time => lose the level) is more appropriate for the arcadey early days of video game design. If you're not getting paid per play, it's a good idea to tone down the frustration of being half a second too slow - and, while you're at it, make the game playable by people which physical limitations which make them slower than the average player - by using soft time limits. In other words, out of time means no time bonus, but you can still complete the level. (As an example, see my game [The Track Controller](http://www.funorb.com/info.ws?game=trackcontroller)). Then you can get into achievements for completing X levels with time bonus, etc. (Not sure why I didn't think of that back then).

Comment: Because if people can retry them they don't really have to obey the limit.

Comment: Well, hand designed puzzle levels (that have no random elements in them) will have the same best solution, which means after a few tries it just becomes a game of how fast you can input your solution. Unless it's a puzzle game with many possible solutions that is, and the challenge is to find that best solution. ''edit'': gah, ninja'd!

Comment: @eBusiness, "because" seems to be defending some assertion, but I'm at a loss to know which.

Comment: @kamziro, what's your point? That hand-designed puzzle games don't have replay value? True to a point, but I don't see what it has to do with time limits (especially when you bear in mind that I'm arguing for time bonuses rather than hard limits).

Comment: @Peter, well, the time limit would mean nothing, because on the second try you already know about the puzzle which was hand-designed. If you run out of time from the first attempt, one can just re-input the solution so far from the first attempt. Same with time bonuses, it just becomes a contest of input speed, which is not generally the point of puzzle games.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, sorry I see that my comment needs a better context definition. It is a response to the very first sentence in you post.

Comment: @kamziro, if the puzzle game has fixed levels then the point is to complete all the levels. The value of bonuses for optimal use of resources (whether time or something else) is to provide something on top to give some replay value. With the game I linked, some players did replay it a lot to get achievements and highscores. Others probably played it through once and left it. I don't see having both options as something negative. (Oh, and try writing down the solutions for the later puzzles - they're quite long).

Comment: That's an awesome game, by the way, and my kids are going to love playing it!  Also, the "Paused" screen is brilliant.

Comment: Strongly agree with the comments that it's not just about input speed.  Putting a time limit on a hand-crafted puzzle means there are two end-goals: finish the puzzles for more casual players, and min-max your time for hardcore players.  Finding the most optimal solution becomes an additional puzzle-goal on top of finding a solution.  It may not be the game you want to make (or even the game you want to play) but saying that time-limited hand-crafted puzzle games are _invalid_ is going much too far.

Comment: @GrandOpener, the point about adding replay value for those who want to find the fastest of multiple solutions is a valuable one which isn't mentioned in any answer. You should consider writing a full answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, but after considering what I would write, I think my answer would end up being too similar to what you786 wrote in the accepted answer.  Point #4 there captures the essence of what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, the harder it is in the first place the less need for a time limit. Bejeweled wouldn't work very well without some sort of time control, in more complicated games the limit may just be annoying.

You could make multiple different game modes with different timing systems, try out what works and give the player some options.

Answer (score 0):

Tetris and Doctor Mario have time limits in the sense that you have to act on every brick within a given time, and the time allocated becomes more scarce as the game becomes faster.

Doctor Mario for example, has a specific puzzle to solve with bricks that fall fast like tetris, and after a given time limit the game becomes impossible to play due to the speed of play.

It's a very popular game system which gives a constant and increasing sense of pace and anticipation, of continual time pressure on the player.

Given the sales figures of those to games, You can say that suspense inducing, continuous rather than final time constraints and fast thinking can be a very challenging and interesting attribute for a game.